# c# How to get filepaths for ALL items in a resource folder

Tags: c#, wpf, list, file, resources

I'm trying to create a list with BitmapImages like this.

```
List<BitmapImage> Images = new List<BitmapImage>
{
    new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/Car.bmp", UriKind.Relative)),
};
```

Right now I'm adding one image manually from the resource \Images\, but I don't want to do that for all 68 images.
Is there a way to make a method, that will look through the resources \Images\, and output a list of all the BitmapImage paths like above?

something like.

```
Foreach(Item in Images)
{
    List.add(ItemPath + ItemName)
}
```

Here is a picture of the folder am talking about:

[image: Image of folder structure]

Answer (score 8):

Here how you can get files by pattern

```
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"Images");
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.bmp"))
{
    // there is file name
}
```

Comment: @MongZhu updated answer, now here I get current folder of executing assembly and get all files by extension